# ubuntu chromium wrong html rendering

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, web, chromium

HTML rendering in ubuntu chromium browser shows wrong

When I load this html...

```
<ol><li>09522869</li><ol><li><a href="http://localhost/pat_book/cm/rc/1d97c261216923c39d1cf0af9b59966a/09522869_892_1">892_1</li>

    <li><b>892_0&nbsp;&nbsp;&#10004;</b>

</li><li><a href="http://localhost/pat_book/cm/rc/1d97c261216923c39d1cf0af9b59966a/09522869_892_2">892_2</li></ol></ol>
```

Here in the second 'li' item - I don't add any 'a' tag (anchor tag) but it shows a 'a' tag automatically in chrome browser with href of previous 'li' 'a'

You can see it save above code in a html file and open it in chrome browser

my ubuntu chromium version
Version 32.0.1700.107 Ubuntu 12.04 (32.0.1700.107-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~20140204.866.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed. You are missing closing `</a>` for *both* your `<a>` tags, and you have extra opening `<ol>` tags:

```
<ol><li>09522869</li><ol>
```

If your intent is to nest lists, your sub-`<ol>` needs to be contained in an `<li>`:

```
<ol>
  <li> Item
    <ol>
      <li> Nested item
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: <ol><li>09522869<ol><li><a href="http://localhost/pat_book/cm/rc/1d97c261216923c39d1cf0af9b59966a/09522869_892_1">892_1</li>
    
    <li><b>892_0&nbsp;&nbsp;&#10004;</b>
    
</li><li><a href="http://localhost/pat_book/cm/rc/1d97c261216923c39d1cf0af9b59966a/09522869_892_2">892_2</li></ol></li></ol>

Comment: i also use this code but its shows wrong, can u explain how it's a malformed

Comment: Have you considered just feeding it into an HTML validator? http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: i think it's a rendering problem in chromium browser

Comment: @lintocheeran You are wrong. Chromium is working just fine, it's your HTML is written incorrectly.

Comment: <ol>
<li>09522869
 <ol>
  <li><a href="#">892_1</li>
        <li><b>892_0&nbsp;&nbsp;&#10004;</b></li>
        <li><a href="#">892_2</li>
    </ol>
</li>
</ol>

Comment: You are still not closing your `<a>` tags! **Read** my answer! You need matching closing tags, `</a>`, for both of your opening `<a>` tags. This is why why your middle `<li>` is being considered part of the previous `<a>`; *you're not closing it*.